# Azure durable function Orchestrator marked as completed but there are several activities not triggered

Tags: python, azure, azure-durable-functions

I developed a durable function that runs every day and calls an activity function between 0-1000 times (depending on the number of rows in the database that day).

In the begging everything was working well, even when there were thousands of rows in the database. But a few days ago I checked the logs and the Orchestrator is always in a "completed" status just a few minutes after it started, even if it was suppose to call the activity function hundreds of times.

**Now the for loop in the Orchestrator is not doing what it's suppose to do: call the activity function n times (depending on the number of rows in the dataframe).**

Here you have the timer that trigger the Orchestrator:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df


async def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest, starter: str) -> None:
    client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
    instance_id = await client.start_new("DownloadsOrchestrator-v2_5", None, None)
    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
```

Here you have the function.json from the timer:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 0 4 * * *"
    },
    {
      "name": "starter",
      "type": "durableClient",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here you have the Orchestrator:

```
import logging
from os import getenv

import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df

from pyodbc import connect
from pandas import DataFrame



def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):

    # Dados para BD:
    server = function-to-get-the-value
    database = function-to-get-the-value
    username = function-to-get-the-value
    password = function-to-get-the-value
    driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'


    con_str='Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:'+server+',1433;Database='+database+';Uid='+username+';Pwd='+password+';Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword'

    # SQL que nos dá produtos criados nas últiumas 24h:
    sql = """
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM table_h
    WHERE date_cre BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, SYSDATETIME()) AND SYSDATETIME()
    """

    conn = connect(con_str)

    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute(sql)

    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    products_orc = DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=[col[0] for col in cursor.description])
    
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()


    prods_loop_orc = products_orc[['Referencia', 'Marca']]
    prods_loop_orc = prods_loop_orc.drop_duplicates(keep="last", inplace=False)
    prods_loop_orc.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    logging.info("Products left to process: " + str(len(prods_loop_orc.index)))


    # list to return:
    results_list = [] 

    for i in range(0, len(prods_loop_orc)):
        #i=0

        data = products_orc.loc[products_orc['Referencia'] == prods_loop_orc['Referencia'][i]]

        data = data.to_dict()

        result = yield context.call_activity('DownloadImages-v2_5', data)

        results_list.append(result)

    return results_list

main = df.Orchestrator.create(orchestrator_function)
```

function.json from the Orcherstrator:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "context",
      "type": "orchestrationTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

The DownloadImages-v2_5 activity function:

```
python code that imports several packages and downloads images to a specific folder.
```

function.json from the activity:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "activityTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

Today the function started at 4AM and it was already completed at 4:06AM. In the last Orchestrator's log I can see my message "Products left to process: 310". And if I visit the database, I can confirm that we still had 310 rows to process.

**So why the Orchestrator was marked as complete even when there were hundreds of rows in the for loop to be processed?**

Comment: You really should not do database queries in an orchestrator, I'm not 100% sure about the Python version but in .NET the orchestrator function is replayed each time there is a result from an activity. You should put the initial query in an activity and use the result from that.

Comment: Hey! But if I do that, how would I know how many times the activity has to run? This query is basically to understand how many times I have to call the activity, so I can't put it inside the activity function.

Comment: You can have one activity function that figures out how many times it will need to run the other activity. That function's result would be what you now fetch from DB. Then in orchestrator you use that result instead of the DB query. (it'll stay the same throughout the iterations and won't repeat that query)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about a solution right after I posted my reply to your first comment.
Since I have a trigger function, I changed the code and the database query is now right before I start the Orchestrator.
I tested a table with 310 rows and it worked fine. So maybe the database query was actually getting in the way?

Comment: By the way: you are correct when you say "the orchestrator function is replayed each time there is a result from an activity". It's not just in .NET, Python follows the same behaviour.